# how I can run parts of SQL query separate in pgAdmin4?

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

I want to running these different parts of query separate, how I can do this via pqAdmin4 ?

[image]

Comment: just select the specific query and run

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the part of the query you want to run and click on execute button and pgAdmin4 will run only that selected query.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: While this is the way, it's inconvenient and I hoped for a shortcut to run the query where the cursor is at.

In Oracle SQL Developer, that's easy using CTRL+RETURN. [There's still no shortcut to do so in v6.9](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/development/keyboard_shortcuts.html#query-tool)...